# can I use JSON types with planetscale and prisma?

Tags: mysql, jsonb, prisma, mysql-json, planetscale

I'm using Prisma to define a schema, and planetscale to host the DB.
this means using the mysql driver with prisma.

I would like to use JSON types, but can't seem to get them to work

planetscale supports it for mysql
https://planetscale.com/blog/the-mysql-json-data-type

prisma supports it for mysql
https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-fields/working-with-json-fields

but doesn't seem to work together?

is planetscale same as MySql? or different? not listed here:
https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/database-reference/database-features
and it says to use the mysql driver.

https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/using-prisma-with-planetscale#what-is-planetscale.

After adding a field to my schema:

```
model Tune {
  cloudFiles              Json? // source cloud files
...
```

I do `prisma generate` and `prisma dbpush` without problems.

But on trying to use the field I get the error:

```
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'cloudFiles' does not exist in type 'Without<TuneUncheckedCreateInput, TuneCreateInput> & TuneCreateInput'.ts(2322)
```

and digging through the generated prisma types   `export type TuneCreateInput = {` doesn't have any mention of the `cloudFiles` JSON field I tried to add.

So, not sure if I'm doing something wrong or just these different systems aren't interacting together properly?

Comment: Can you share the code where you are using the field `cloudFiles`? If possible sharing the schema and the query will help us easily troubleshoot this.